# Placing a textbox inside a textbox and making it deletable like text

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am placing a textbox within a textbox like this:

[image]

I have achieved the above with the following code:

```
        var innerTextBox = new TextBox();
        innerTextBox.Width = 100;

        var outerTextBox = new TextBox();
        outerTextBox.Multiline = true;
        outerTextBox.Height = 100;
        outerTextBox.Width = 200;

        outerTextBox.Controls.Add(innerTextBox);
```

1. Now the problem is that the text goes behind the textbox, how can I prevent that?
2. I would also like the textbox inside to behave as text so that one can delete it with backspace just like regular text.

Can somebody please point me to the right direction?

This is a winforms project.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The primary question is: WHY?

Comment: It's for a project that includes being able to add controls within controls and to delete them dynamically. I'm just using the textbox inside as an example. It's actually a panel with multiple objects.

Comment: Have you tried it with a `Panel` and the objects you need? They're designed to be containers so you're less likely to face issues like this (unless you plan to have a Textbox within a Textbox within a Panel ;) ).

Comment: yes I did try, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried txt.BringToFront or txt.SendToBack?

What I'm getting from your question is that you want transparency for the textbox in front. Have you tried to use a label? Labels are transparent by default and can be modified when the textbox's text is changed.